# Compare n number of lists and return matching objects in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a search method, where I can search for example like this: "Fish, Ball, Horse". I only want to get results where ALL is matching.

I am doing my search like this:

```
string[] splitted = searchText.Split (',');

for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++) 
{
    splitted [i] = splitted [i].Trim ();
}

List<List<Card>> allMatches = new List<List<Card>> ();
foreach (string search in splitted) 
{
    if (search.Length == 0)
        continue;
    allMatches.Add( DataBase.SearchCards (search));
}
```

Now, how do I get a new List with the Cards objects that are in ALL of the arrays in this list: `List<List<Card>> allMatches` ?

My implementation is working, I just need help with implementing this pseudo code-method:

```
ListOfAllCardsInLists(List<List<Card>> listOfCardLists)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
List<Card> cardsThatAreInAllLists = ListOfAllCardsInLists(allMatches);
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not LINQ ;-)

Comment: Define "matching", I don't fully understand your criteria here.  How is your current implementation not working?  And why can't you use LINQ, are you limited to a much older version of .NET in an existing codebase?  (If so, it would be best to indicate that in the tags.)

Comment: I cannot make sense of this question. What is allCardsMatching for? In your snippet it is never used.

Comment: No is not a home work. I am using xamarin.forms and foreach isnt there due to wp8 (i think). AllCardsMatching is The array in which to put all cards that have a match in ALL The search params.

Comment: My implementation is working, but i want to grab the cards that are in all of the arrays. (i.e they have a match on all of the search strings) i dont know how to do this. I got stuck in a uber nestled foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I did it. This could probably be optimized tons of times:

```
        List<Card> results = new List<Card>(allMatches.FirstOrDefault ());

        for (int i = 1; i < allMatches.Count (); i++) {
            List<Card> other = allMatches [i];

            List<Card> toRemove = new List<Card> ();
            foreach(Card e in results) {

            //This comparison can be interpreted as other.Contains(e)
                if (other.Any(b => b.ID == e.ID)) {
                    continue;
                }
                toRemove.Add (e);
            }

            foreach (Card e in toRemove) {
                results.Remove (e);
            }
        }
```